# Setting character encoding in EL way

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, el

How can we achieve following in JSTL -

```
<% response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

I know we can refer to response object as below but how we can we call setter method?

```
${pageContext.response}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's supposed to be done by the following line in top of your JSP:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Or, if you want to apply this on *all* JSPs, add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [JSP/Servlet response](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletResponse)

Comment: [link](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html). As per this link For web components, three encodings must be considered:  1.Request  2.Page (JSP pages)  3.Response

Comment: Did you *read* the article behind your link? Read the section "Response encoding". You'll see that it is for JSP pages been set based on page encoding. See also the "See also" link at the bottom of my answer. If you're still having problems with getting it right, you should elaborate that in more detail.